# I can't get the right values from my dictionary. Any suggestions?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have everything right in my code (I think) except the part where I get the correct names from my dictionary.

My code is:

```
studentdirectory = {"Andrew": ["Jane", "John"], "Betsy": ["Ellen", "Nigel"], "Louise": ["Natalie", "Louis"], "Chad": ["Mary", "Joseph"]}

def menu():
    print
    print ("Enter 1 to retrieve the mother's name of the child.")
    print ("Enter 2 to retrieve the father's name of the child.")
    print ("Enter 3 to retrieve the name of both parents of the child.")
    print ("Enter 0 to quit.")
    print
    while True:
        choice = input("Enter your choice now: ")
        if (choice >= 0) and (choice<= 3) and (int(choice) == choice):
            return choice
        else:
            print ("Your choice is invalid. Please try again with options 0 to 3.")

for key in studentdirectory:
    mom = studentdirectory[key][0]
    dad = (studentdirectory[key][1])

def main():
    while True:
        choice = menu()
        if choice == 0:
            break
        else:
            name = raw_input("Enter the name of the child: ")
            if studentdirectory.has_key(name):
                if choice == 1:
                    print "The name of the child's mother is ", mom, "."
                elif choice == 2:
                    print "The name of the child's father is ", dad, "."
                else:
                    print "The name of the child's parents are ", mom, " and ", dad, "."
            else:
                print "The child is not in the student directory."


 main()
```

I would like to keep my code as close to this as possible. I just need help in understanding how to get separate values in the dictionary, because right now for every mom and dad I only get Louise's parents back. How do i fix this??
This is Python Language.

Answer (score 0):

```
if studentdirectory.has_key(name):
    mom = studentdirectory[key][0]
    dad = (studentdirectory[key][1])
```

And delete the `for key in studentdirectory` loop part

Because when you get a student name in the main loop.Your original code only return a const `mom` and `dad` varible,which comes from your `for` loop above the `main()` defination.

And logically

> You can only get the parents name **after** you have the child's name

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the values of `mom` and `dad` in a loop, but overwriting them each time, so they're always set to the value of the last loop cycle (Louise in your case). You should define them when you need them only instead:

```
def main():
    while True:
        choice = menu()
        if choice == 0:
            break
        else:
            name = raw_input("Enter the name of the child: ")
            if studentdirectory.has_key(name):  
                mom = studentdirectory[name][0]
                dad = studentdirectory[name][1]
                if choice == 1:
                    print "The name of the child's mother is ", mom, "."
                elif choice == 2:
                    print "The name of the child's father is ", dad, "."
                else:
                    print "The name of the child's parents are ", mom, " and ", dad, "."
            else:
                print "The child is not in the student directory."
```